# в скрипте есть логин и пароль при подключении к бд, как их ввод вывести через командную строку

Tags: python-3.x

В скрипте есть необходимость ввести логин и пароль к базе данных, которые не хотелось бы "светить", как можно вывести ввод логина и пароля через командную строку?

Comment: Можно вводить например через [`getpass.getpass()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getpass.html).

Answer (score 0):

Если под "светить" понимается "сохранять внутри скрипта в явном виде", то можно для них сделать переменные, а данные от пользователя брать командой input().

```
# В начале скрипта спрашиваем у пользователя логин и пароль
login = input("Введите логин: ")
password = input("Введите пароль: ")
```

Обратите внимание, это не скроет вводимые данные в командной строке.